# Specific time-zones string

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, clock

I'm looking to state business hours alongside a live clock stating what time it is where we're operating. Shown in a12-hour clock which also states AM / PM

I'm quite a JS rookie so I seek assistance to fill in the blanks and help me write the JS that will show what time it is in the EST time zone. I've researched Moment.js but can't figure out how it works properly.

And maybe there's an even more innovative way to do this.

Thanks a lot!

```css
section {
  width:100vw;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#colon{
  animation: blink 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  49% { opacity: 0;}
  50% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="clock">
    Business hours
    <span id="hours">h</span>
    <span id="colon">:</span>
    <span id="minutes">m</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: [You should not choose Moment.js for a new project](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  What is your actual question?  Perhaps you are looking for `Date.toLocaleTimeString` with the `timeZone` option?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the local time in your desired timezone with Vanilla JS by using [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

We can then split using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the hour, minute and meridiem (am/pm) components.

I've wrapped all this up in `showTime()` and `showClock()` functions, which accept timeZone arguments.

In this case I've used [`America/New_York`](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/new-york) which is most likely the timezone you should use, however you can change to any [`IANA zone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

showClock queues itself to run every 1000 milliseconds, again you can change as required.

```js
function showTime(date, timeZone) {
    const [hour, minute, meridiem] = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone, hourCycle: 'h12', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}).split(/[: ]/);
    document.getElementById('hours').innerText = hour;
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = minute + ' ' + meridiem;
}

function showClock(timeZone) {
    showTime(new Date(), timeZone);
    setTimeout(showClock, 1000, timeZone)
}

showClock('America/New_York')
```

```css
section {
  width:100vw;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#colon{
  animation: blink 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  49% { opacity: 0;}
  50% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="clock">
    Business hours
    <span id="hours">h</span>
    <span id="colon">:</span>
    <span id="minutes">m</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can also do this using [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon), a successor to moment.js. As @matt-johnson-pint says, you should not choose moment.js for a new project.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

function showTime(date, timeZone) {
    const dt = DateTime.now().setZone(timeZone);
    document.getElementById('hours').innerText = dt.toFormat('hh');
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = dt.toFormat('mm a');
}

function showClock(timeZone) {
    showTime(new Date(), timeZone);
    setTimeout(showClock, 1000, timeZone)
}

showClock('America/New_York')
```

```css
section {
  width:100vw;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#colon{
  animation: blink 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  49% { opacity: 0;}
  50% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<section>
  <div class="clock">
    Business hours
    <span id="hours">h</span>
    <span id="colon">:</span>
    <span id="minutes">m</span>
  </div>
</section>
```